Hodge dual of dy in Minkowski space
I'm following the formula for the Hodge dual as follows
$$
(\star \omega)_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_{m-p}}
=\frac{1}{p!} \sqrt{|g|} \varepsilon_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_{m-p}\nu_1\cdots\nu_p} \omega^{\nu_1\cdots\nu_p}
$$
As the case for $\mathrm dy$ in 4D Minkowski space with signature ($1,-1,-1,-1$), I got
$$
(\star \mathrm d y)_{013}=\varepsilon_{0132} (\mathrm dy)^2=\varepsilon_{0132}  g^{22}(\mathrm dy)_2=-1\times(-1) =1.
$$
Thus
$$
\star \mathrm dy=\mathrm dt\wedge \mathrm dx\wedge \mathrm dz.
$$
But the correct answer should be $-1$ in the front.

The cleanest notation that works for all metric signatures in 4D is found in
Wikipedia:
$$\tag{1}
\star\,(dx^\mu)=\eta^{\mu\lambda}\varepsilon_{\lambda\nu\rho\sigma}\frac1{3!}dx^\nu\wedge dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma\,.
$$
I just learned here that there might be different conventions for the sign of the Levi-Civita symbol but thankfully Wikipedia mentions clearly that in (1) they use the convention $\varepsilon_{0123}=1\,.$

Now for the metric $\eta^{\mu\lambda}$ assume West coast convention $(+---)$ which is popular in particle physics.

By the anti symmetry of $\varepsilon_{\lambda\nu\rho\sigma}$ and the anti symmetry of
$dx^\nu\wedge dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma$ in all indices it is clear that
when summing over $\nu,\rho,\sigma$ we can just take one term
where $\nu<\rho<\sigma$ and drop the factor $\frac1{3!}\,.$
That is because any permutation in an index pair leads to a sign change of the form $(-1)(-1)=1\,.$ Another drastic simplification arises because $\eta^{\mu\lambda}$ is diagonal.
For $\mu=2\,,$ we have $dx^\mu=dy$ and therefore
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\star\,dy&=
\underbrace{\eta^{22}\varepsilon_{2013}}_{(-1)(+1)}\, dt \wedge dx\wedge dz=-\,dt\wedge dx\wedge dz
\end{align}
which is the answer that you said is correct.
It is quite obvious, too, that with the East coast convention $(-+++)$ and Levi-Civita symbol normalized to $\varepsilon_{0123}=1$ we get a plus sign:
$$\tag{3}
\star\,dy=dt\wedge dx\wedge dz
$$
which agrees with WP because they write this as
$$\tag{4}
\star\,dy=-\,dt\wedge\color{red}{dz}\wedge\color{red}{dx}\,.
$$
